# oop instantiation pythonic practices

Tags: oop, pyqt, python

I've got the code below, and I was planning on making several classes all within the same "import". I was hoping to instantiate each class and get a return value with the widgets I'm making.

This isn't really a PyQt question at all, more of a "good practices" question, as I'll have a class for each widget.

Should I make functions that return the widgets that were created, if so how? How do I ensure it is difficult to directly instantiate the class if that is the best method for what I'm after?

I'd like to be able to do something like ....

```
tabs = wqTabWidget( ['firstTab', 'Second', 'Last Tab'] )
```

or (which ever is a better practice)

```
tabs = wqInstance.createTabs( ['firstTab', 'Second', 'Last Tab'] )
```

Here's my class so far....

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore as qc
from PyQt4 import QtGui as qg

class wqTabWidget(qg.QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):

        apply(qg.QTabWidget.__init__,(self, ))
        tabList = []
        tabNames = args[0] 

        for name in tabNames:
            tabWidget = qg.QWidget()
            self.addTab(tabWidget,  name)
            tabList.append( { name:tabWidget } )

    print 'hi'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qg.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = wqTabWidget(['hi',  'there',  'and',  'stuff'])
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer will be decided if the list of tabs can be changed at runtime. If this widget really only supports adding a set of tabs, but never changing or appending new ones, the list of tabs should come from the initializer. Otherwise you should also add a method to do the job. Consider the `QLabel` widget which can set the label's text in the initializer and through the `setText` method.

Other code idea tips.

Your initializer's arguments is a little confusing because you accept an arbitrary number of arguments, but only do something with the first one, and expect it to be a list of strings. A clear list of arguments is important.

Your use of `apply` to call the base class initializer is unnecessary. Change the code to simply `qg.QTabWidget.__init__(self)`

When creating a PyQt widget, I almost always prefer to allow a "parent" argument, even when I know the widget is going to be a toplevel widget. This is what all the built in Pyqt methods do, and feels like good practice to follow.

I also can't see the reason to store a list of tabs, with each one being a single element dictionary. I suspect you won't need to keep your own list of tabs and tab names. The QTabWidget can answer all questions about the contents.

If I were to bend this example code to my own preferences it would look like this.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore as qc
from PyQt4 import QtGui as qg


class wqTabWidget(qg.QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent, tabNames):
        qg.QTabWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.createTabs(tabNames)

    def createTabs(tabNames):
        for name in tabNames:
            tabWidget = qg.QWidget()
            self.addTab(tabWidget,  name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qg.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = wqTabWidget(None, ['hi',  'there',  'and',  'stuff'])
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```